# Using long division to identify a polynomial quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Identify the ring $\Bbb Z[x] / \langle x+1, x^2+1\rangle$

I've seen a few approaches on how to tackle these kind of problems and in this case the identification seems to be $$\Bbb Z[x] / \langle x+1, x^2+1\rangle \cong \Bbb F_2.$$

However I haven't seen an approach with long division. Computing the division $$\dfrac{x^2+1}{x+1}$$ I got that $$x^2+1=x\left(x+1\right)-\left(x+1\right)+2$$ so I'll get a remainder of $2$ which I suspect is no coincidence?

Since $x+1 = 0$ in our ring we have that $x^2+1=2$ so the ring simplifies to $$\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x+1,2\rangle = \Bbb Z_2[x] /\langle x+1\rangle$$

Still the long division doesn't seem to get rid of the linear term $x+1$? I think I need to get clever here and consider some elements of the form $$p(x)(x+1), \ p(x) \in \Bbb Z_2[x]?$$

Comment: By the division algorithm, every $p \in \Bbb Z_2[x]$ can be written as $p = (x+1)q + a$ for some $q \in \Bbb Z_2[x]$ and some $a \in \Bbb Z_2$. Thus, in the quotient, $p$ is just $a$.

Comment: For any field $K$ we have $K[X]/\langle X-a\rangle\simeq K$ via the substitution homomorphism $f(X)\mapsto f(a)$. This is just the Remainder Theorem cf Long Division.